# Why does the question start with "who" not need "do"?

Tags: grammar

> Who told you that ....

Why does this kind of question not need "do"

> Who did tell you that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the pronoun "who" is replacing the subject of the sentence, not the object.

Compare

> What eats mice?  (answer Cats eat mice)
>
> What do mice eat? (answer Mice eat seeds and nuts)

With "what" questions, the first type is fairly rare, but it is common enough with "who" questions.

> Who told Mary?  (answer John told Mary)
>
> Who did Mary tell? (answer Mary told John)

Comment: Perfect answer. Appologize again for accepting an answer in a short time.